# Submit a form from a Php while loop using JQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have searched and searched and havent been able to fix my issue.. help ;)

I have a form I create in a while loop.  I then use AJAX to process it..  Problem is it only will sumbit first form, even if I click the second form.  Assume this is due to each form needing a unique ID.  Im having a problem doing that... any help would be wonderful.

**My Php for form**

```
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >';
echo ' <tr>';
echo ' <td style="color:#bbb">Team Name</td>';
echo '<td style="color:#bbb">Event Name</td>';
echo ' <td style="color:#bbb">Event Level</td>';
echo ' <td style="color:#bbb">Comments</td>';
echo '<td style="color:#bbb">&nbsp;</td>';
echo ' <td style="color:#bbb">&nbsp;</td>';
echo ' </tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pendingresult)) {
    $id = $row['reg_id'];
    print "<form id=\"$id\" name=\"CDs\" method=\"post\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">";
    echo '<tr class="commentContainer">';
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"team_name\" value=\"$row[team_name]\"</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"reg_id\" value=\"$row[reg_id]\"</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"team_level\" value=\"$row[team_level]\"</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"notes\" value=\"$row[comments]\"</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<td class=\"delete\" align=\"center\" id=" . $row['reg_id'] . " width=\"10\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$row[reg_id]\"><img src=\"admin/images/delete.png\" border=\"0\" ></a></td>";
    echo "<td class=\"approve\" align=\"center\" id=" . $id . " width=\"10\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$row[reg_id]\"><img src=\"admin/images/approve.png\" border=\"0\" ></a></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

**My AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
$(function () {
  $(".approve").click(function () {
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent('tr:first');
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var string = 'id=' + id;
    var formData = this.form.id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "approve.php",
      data: $("formData").serialize(),
      cache: false,
      success: function () {
        commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function () {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: you are inserting your form tag in a table, directly on place of the TR, that's bad and I'm not sure about the behaviour of your form. You should emmbed a full table in each form instead. Secondly, you should check what contain your `this.form.id`.

Comment: You are using the same id for your FORM and for your TD, an id should be unique on the page. Moreover, I'm not sure the $("formData") will return something. You should debug your code with some console.debug

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax change

data: $("formData").serialize()

to

data: $("form#"+id).serialize()

it will catch the current form you are processing

Answer (score 0):

You are using form fields in while loop so that means they are array of input fields with same name.

So you need to combine them into one variable and pass it accordingly.

**Example**

```
var team_name = $("input[name=team_name]").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

And So on for others fields.

Try it.

Comment: inputs with the same name is not a problem. And each form has an unique id which is enough to get the good one.

Comment: Problem is I dont know how to pass the ID to the AJAX ;(

Comment: you can define it as url: "approve.php?id="+ID

Comment: Im trying to pass the ID to the AJAX though not the approve.phpdata: $("formData").serialize(),